# Jquery Internet Explorer 8 $(window) undefined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

When I use the JQuery method $(window) in Chrome, FF etc. it returns [ DOMWindow ], when I use it in Internet Explorer 8 it returns null. How can I get the window jquery object in IE8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like jQuery conflicting with something else using `$` (this probably only happens in the developer console). Try `jQuery(window)`.